# Why is KeyboardAvoidingView component not working?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to make a 1:1 chat, however when I try to tap on the TextInput the KeyboardAvoidingView is not working, I am not sure if this is something with my styles or if I am not using it correctly, here you can find my [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@niklaus91/dfb099)

And this is the code:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    placeholder: 'Write a message...',
    text: ''
    };
}

render() {
  return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 20}} behavior="padding" enabled>
        <View style={styles.messageView}>
          <Message
            message="Hi! First Message"
            styleMessage={'one'}
          />
          <Message
            message="Hi! Second Message"
            styleMessage={'two'}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.textInput}
              selectionColor={BLUE}
              placeholderTextColor={LIGHT_GRAY}
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
              placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
              value={this.state.text}
              onEndEditing={() => {console.log(1+1)}}
            />
          </View>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.sendButton}>
            <Ionicons name="md-send" size={25} color='#FFFFFF' style={{textAlign: 'center'}}/>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>


      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this Context you only need to change

> behavior="padding"

for

> behavior="height"

and it will starts working correctly on both plataforms (Android/iOS)

Personally I recommend you to use instead KeyboardAwareScrollView from react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view package ([Link](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)) because it let you configure easier and faster the behavior of it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, changing from padding to height solved the problem, I will be checking late the react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view but thanks again!

Comment: i use the " react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view package" as u said and its not working also, can u help me please ?

Comment: yes @shira, i can try to help you. You should better open a new question and paste your code